# jQuery append - html wrote doesn't trigger other events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe i should be more specific.
I've a javascript function, called from here:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" onkeyup="Trova('Text1');" />
```

The function, search into an array and, with jquery, draws new rows into a table (ID #tabdest):

```
$("#tabdest").append('<tr><td class="preview" nome="' + nomi[i] + '" >' + nomi[i] + '</td></tr>');
```

Everythings is ok until now. Into my .js file I've this function that shoud be executed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".preview").mousemove(function (event) {
        ...
```

This function works correctly if I write a table manually but doesn't if jQuery write it.

I'm sorry for my terrible English, hope to find help
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the other answers have correctly identified that you should be using event delegation (through the use of jQuery's `on` function) I wanted to explain a bit about how your code is currently working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".preview").mousemove(function (event) {
        ...
```

Translated into words this is: When the document is ready search for all elements with class "preview" and add an event handler to these elements for the mouse move event. jQuery doesn't do magic.

```
$('.preview')...
```

is basically doing

```
document.getElementsByClassName('preview')
```

It's not doing any kind of mapping or binding to the DOM. This means when you add a new element with the class "preview" the code that added the event handlers would need to run again to pick this new element up.

Using:

```
$("#tabdest").on('mousemove', '.preview', function(e) { });
```

Binds the event handler to the "tabdest" element (which doesn't change) and when a user clicks on a child of this element (one of your newly created elements) the event bubbles up the DOM and runs this function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$("#tabdest").on('mousemove','.preview',function(event){ ...  });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `preview` tabel cell is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#tabdest').on('mousemove', '.preview', function(event) {        
    alert('testlink'); 
    //....
});
```

This will attach your event to any table cell with class `preview` within the `#tabdest` table element, reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.